Do You Need 2 Bundle Ids and 2 Targets to Use Swift Data and CloudKit for Dev and Prod?
I’m using Swift Data and CloudKit, with a private container.
When developing my understanding is that you should have a target with com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment key set to “Development”, so that you can push the schema and not mess with production data.
And a target for prod with the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment key set to “Production”, as that’s what Test Flight requires, as well as the prod release.
The problem is that when I run each target it overwrites the app on my phone, because they both have the same bundle id (as it’s the same app in the App Store).
If I:

Install Dev target -> add data -> run Prod target -> my Dev data shows up in "Prod".
Unless... I do an uninstall-fresh install of Prod. Then the Dev data doesn't show up.

It seems like Swift Data is using the same container for both targets but cloudkit is kinda using 2 different databases? ...?
Does anyone have any idea what the best practice might be?
Wondering if I should setup

2 app store apps (bundle ids)
2 cloudkit containers
The project then has 2 targets
Prod: uses the Production container in Production mode (...except for when you have to push the schema using Development)
Dev: uses the Development container in Development mode

Any help appreciated!
I'm initing like this:

@MainActor
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    var container: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
            let schema = Schema([
                MyModel.self,
                MyOtherModel.self,
            ])
        
        let config = ModelConfiguration(cloudKitDatabase: .private("iCloud.com.me.myapp"))
  
            
            do {
                container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: config)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
            }
        }
    // ... 
}

